# Can we bind service created by extending IntentService class?

Tags: android

I was wondering that we can create service by extending service or intent service class. Can we bind service created by extending IntentService class?

Comment: Yes we can.by the way IntentService is subclass of Service class.

Comment: `IntentService`  runs on background thread co it will stop as soon as its work done . On the other hand `Service` can run continuously in background. So its completely depends on what exactly you want to perform on Service.